# Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop - screen doesn't work: no power, brightness is 0%

Tags: display, power, dell-inspiron, brightness

There is a laptop - **Dell Inspiron 1545**.

A problem is **a brightness of a screen is 0%** (when BIOS starts, Windows works - all time). I can barely see a picture on a screen at a big angle (it seems like the screen doesn't work totally). **The screen doesn't have the power**.

BIOS doesn't report any errors.

You can see that 0% brightness effect if you have a turn off screen button on your laptop. Try to turn of and you must see a picture on a screen anyway but at a very big angle.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my (admittedly somewhat limited) experience, this is generally caused by a non-working inverter which will need to be replaced.

Comment: I would venture to say this is probably the case. Definitely the first thing to check/try replacing.